# text box input height

Tags: html, css

I made the size of the box bigger. it look bigger int the dream weaver design view but does not seem to work in the browsers.

```
<input type="text" **height="60%"**  name=" item" align="left" />
```

Answer (score 19):

If you want to increase the *height* of the input field, you can specify `line-height` css property for the input field.

```
input {
    line-height: 2em; // 2em is (2 * default line height)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I came here looking for making an input that's actually multiple lines. Turns out I didn't want an input, I wanted a textarea. You can set height or line-height as other answers specify, but it'll still just be one line of a textbox. If you want actual multiple lines, use a textarea instead. The following is an example of a 3-row textarea with a width of 500px (should be a good part of the page, not necessary to set this and will have to change it based on your requirements).

```
<textarea name="roleExplanation" style="width: 500px" rows="3">This role is for facility managers and holds the highest permissions in the application.</textarea>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer has not really added anything new to the other answers provided and your reply does not read all that well, could you rephrase it please.  What should I use instead? textbox? textarea?

Comment: I edited it to add an example. Inputs are only going to be one line, period. You can increase the height of the box but it won't wrap around when you hit the end of the box, it'll keep going. The textarea wraps text around when you type enough to hit the end of the line and starts a new line.

Answer (score 8):

You can define a `class` or `id` for input fields.

Or

```
input {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 6):

Just use CSS to increase it's height:

```
<input type="text" style="height:30px;" name="item" align="left" />
```

Or, often times, you want to increase it's height by using padding instead of specifying an exact height:

```
<input type="text" style="padding: 5px;" name="item" align="left" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Use CSS:

```
<input type="text" class="bigText"  name=" item" align="left" />

.bigText {
    height:30px;
}
```

Dreamweaver is a poor testing tool. It is not a browser.